# making a pending button for each row of a table

Tags: html, jquery, css, ajax, laravel

I should make a button that is in pending status until I click on it and status change to approved in the database and then, the color and the text of the button must change to success without reloading the page.
when the status change to approved or success it must become disabled, I mean shouldn't (toggle).
thanks in advance...

this is the button

```
<button type="submit" id="approve_button" class="btn btn-danger">Pending
</button>
```

Comment: What is the issue and what is your question? Can you share some code?

Comment: @YoannPicquenot Which part of the question did you not understand?

Comment: Technically speaking you didn't ask a question nor did you mention where you are stuck. Nevertheless, it seems like a valid topic so I upvoted it again (someone downvoted probably due to unclear question)

Comment: If I want to be more clear I have to say that I just don't know how to change the text and the color of the button when I click on it . when the status of the button change.

Comment: @Aedan at first the css of the button is danger and it's on pending status, when I click on it, the status should change to approved and the text and the  css also change to success

Comment: Edit your question to make it clearer for everyone to see what. your question is and where you're stuck at.

Comment: @Aedan there is button with class="btn btn-danger", when I click on it the text and the css class should change. I know I should work this with ajax and update the value in database . I'm just wondering how to change the class and the text when I click on it.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the text of the button by doing this:

```
$('#approve_button').text('ChangeYourText');
```

To change the color, if you have your css classes:

```
$('#approve_button').toggleClass('your-class');
```

To handle the click event:

```
$('#approve_button').on('click', () => {
  // put one of those lines above
});
```